# Color of the bootstrap links (light blue?) in rgb?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, colors, hyperlink

Trying to get a border around a link styled with bootstrap (seems to be light blue). Can't find the color in the css file. The border is in another div wrapped around the link. I wanna have the same color between border and link.

Comment: Look harder...it's there.

Comment: http://www.netgfx.com/RGBaZR/ rgb(66,139,202)

Comment: However, here's an interesting fact, you don't need to know the color of the link to apply a border of the same color. There is a color `keyword` --- `currentColor` which just works: `border:1px solid currentColor;` See - http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/wd7wj/7/

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this part:

```
a {
  color: $link-color;
  text-decoration: none;
  &:hover,
  &:focus {
    color: $link-hover-color;
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
  &:focus {
    @include tab-focus();
  }
}
```

This is on _scaffolding.scss and then its call tab-focus mixin.

Note that this is under the scss version of bootstrap.

Basically you have to overwrite this:

```
a:focus {
  outline: thin dotted;
  outline: 5px auto color;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}
```

Place this at the bottom of your bs imports and change color with the one you want.

PS: This is how to solve it, but what Im saying is not the right way to work with BS, but I dont know if you are compiling BS or using a min. version.

Hope it helps